# Ubuntu 12.04 upgrade problem (The package system is broken)

Tags: package-management

The package system is broken

```
Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -f

Details :

The following packages have unmet dependencies:

gir1.2-mutter-3.0: gnome-shell: Depends: libgjs0-libmozjs185-1.0 but it is a virtual package

Depends: libpulse-mainloop-glib0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.1 is installed

Depends: libpulse0 (>= 1:0.99.1) but 1:1.1-0ubuntu15.1 is installed

Depends: libxfixes3 (>= 1:5.0) but 1:5.0-4ubuntu4 is installed

             Depends: gnome-shell-common (= 3.5.4+git20120721.r1.dd80f390-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz1) but 3.5.4+git20120721.r1.dd80f390-0ubuntu1~12.04~ricotz1 is installed

libmutter0: Depends: libice6 (>= 1:1.0.0) but 2:1.0.7-2build1 is installed

Depends: libx11-6 (>= 2:1.4.99.1) but 2:1.4.99.1-0ubuntu2 is installed

Depends: libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1) but 1:0.4.3-2build1 is installed

Depends: libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1) but 1:1.1.3-2build1 is installed

Depends: libxrandr2 (>= 2:1.2.99.3) but 2:1.3.2-2 is installed
```

Comment: Are you using PPA's or an unstable release?

Comment: It seems you are using gnome-shell installed from PPA ,you are  [Unstable gnome-shell version](https://live.gnome.org/ThreePointFive). And from which version are you Upgrading your Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

Open the file `/etc/apt/sources.list` and disable all the unstable or third-party repositories. Then run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Also, as mentioned in the snippet you provided, you might have to run `sudo apt-get install -f`.